# gbarcode issue - barcodes not being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using gbarcode with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.7 on Ubuntu 12.10

In my dev server there is gbarcode version 0.98.20 which works and generates the barcodes. However I have version 0.98.16 on my production server which gives following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/barcodes/ATL-00566.png")
```

Now I know it sounds like a routing issue, but it is not. Problem is that rails is looking for the barcode png in the images/barcodes dir it is not there because the version 0.98.16 did not generate it.

I tried to install 0.98.20 on my production system but I get following error:

```
extconf.rb:10: GNU Barcode is no longer bundled with the gbarcode gem. Please install GNU barcode before installing this gem (Exception)
```

Comment: issue was with ImageMagick in windows. gbarcode 0.98.16 works as well as 0.98.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was with ImageMagick in windows. gbarcode 0.98.16 works as well as 0.98.20.